# mysql:connection OK but response error

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

this is my code:

```
    $Line = mysql_real_escape_string(postVar("showline"));
    $Model = mysql_real_escape_string(postVar("showmodel"));
    $NIK = mysql_real_escape_string(postVar("showNIK"));

          $sql ="SELECT NIK,Line,Model FROM inspection_report";
          $sql.="WHERE NIK='".$NIK."' AND Model LIKE '%".$Model."%' AND Line='".$Line."'";
          $sql.="ORDER BY Inspection_datetime DESC LIMIT 0 , 30";

$dbc=mysql_connect(_SRV, _ACCID, _PWD) or die(_ERROR15.": ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("qdbase") or die(_ERROR17.": ".mysql_error());
$res=mysql_query($sql) or _doError(_ERROR30 . ' (<small>' . htmlspecialchars($sql) . '</small>): ' . mysql_error() );  // submit SQL to MySQL and error trap.
$num=mysql_affected_rows();
$objJSON=new mysql2json();
print(trim($objJSON->getJSON($res,$num,'aaData',false)));

mysql_free_result($res);
```

at firebugs shows that connection to process page ok...but at response show error..
where is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that is PHP.

Add the command `echo $sql;` after your lines above. I bet your query is malformed, i.e. no space between the end of the `FROM` clause and the `WHERE`. Same with `ORDER BY`. Happens all the time ;)

Comment: after add a space at them..response not show the data which get from database..why?

Comment: Add the output from the `echo $sql;` to your original post and let's take another look.

Comment: What's the query? Also `echo $num;` after the assignment line. Copy the response and paste it here.

Comment: SELECT NIK,Line,Model FROM inspection_report WHERE NIK='' AND Model LIKE '%%' AND Line='' ORDER BY Inspection_datetime DESC LIMIT 0 , 30{"aaData":[
]}0

Comment: You have no values in your `WHERE` clause. Are `$NIK` and `$Model` set?

Comment: Sorry, I think we are on a different page. Your query is running now, but it is merely not returning any results. You need to ensure that what is coming across in `$_POST` is what you expect. Also, if you expect to see results, you may want to consider defaulting or conditionally adding these conditions in your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

What Jason has said is good and will show you where the error is, which looks like a lack of spaces in the line breaks. Add a space before `WHERE` and another before `ORDER`

Comment: @klox can you do as Jason asked and edit your original post and paste in the output that `echo $sql;` is showing please. The extra code is great but right now a look at the completed query might help us a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a lot easier to write and read my SQL statements by declaring the SQL String within a single set of quotes as in:

```
$sql ="SELECT NIK,Line,Model FROM inspection_report
WHERE NIK='$NIK' AND Model LIKE '%$Model%' AND Line='$Line'
ORDER BY Inspection_datetime DESC LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

This method will also solve your problem with missing spaces between lines.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, you're lacking spaces in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT .... inspection_report";
$sql .= "WHERE NIK=..."
etc...
```

will generate a query string:

```
SELECT ... inspection_reportWHERE NIK=...
                           ^^--- problem is here
```

Notice the lack of a space before the WHERE clause. You have to either modify your string concatenation statements to explicitly include the space:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... inspection_report";
$sql .= " WHERE NIK=..."
         ^---notice the space here
```

or use alternative syntax to build the string. For multi-line string assignments, it's generally always preferable to use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s, *unless* you need to concatenate function call results or constants into the string:

```
$sql = <<<EOL
SELECT ... inspection report
WHERE NIK=...
EOL;
```

PHP will honor the line breaks inside the heredoc, and MySQL will silently treat them as spaces, preserving the integrity of your query.

Comment: I think we both just unlocked the **Patience** badge ;)